# Woocommerce shipment data custom_tracking_link is coming null

Tags: woocommerce, shipping-method

I'm trying to get Woocommerce orders shipment data. I can get provider and tracking number. But can't get link to provider page. There's link in Woocommerce page but not in API.

Woocommerce tracking id with directing link to provider page:

[image: Woocommerce tracking id with directing link to provider page]

Here is what I get from woocommerce API, `custom_tracking_provider` is null:

[image: Here is what I get from woocommerce API, custom_tracking_provider is null]

How can I solve that? Should I write every provider link? But there is so many it will slow down the app.

Comment: Maybe this will help ? https://woocommerce.com/document/shipment-tracking/#section-9